# How can I import a module from another Joomla website?

Tags: joomla

How can I import a module from another Joomla website?

Answer (score 2):

you can easily download the desired module from joomla extensions directory

Answer (score 0):

please mention what is the module u need.

before you post here try from joomla extentions directory.

any way there is an option for getting entire joomla website and rebuilding it as it is.

the component is named as [Akeeba](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606) and another one [Joombackup](http://joomlax.net/downloads/Access---Security/Backup/Jombackup/)

but these are for backup entire joomla website and restore as it is.

there is no option for getting single module from another joomla website(unless u know the webmaster of that website and can get that module or component).

Answer (score 0):

if this website doesn't belong to you, you can't import whatever modules from this. On the contrary, it's quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ftp/phpMyAdmin access to the site you can copy the module folder and asscoatied entry in the modules table. You should also copy any db tables created and used by this module.

Answer (score 0):

if the module you are copying is mod_module, then :
take a copy of /modules/mod_module to some where local e.g.
c:\downloads\mod_module
mod_module will contain something like this:

mod_module.php
mod_module.xml
tmpl (folder)
index.htm

zip up these files into a file called mod_module.zip

use that to install the module on your new site.